# flutter reuse fragment float above other views

Tags: android, flutter, fragment

I have two reuse fragments, and the second on is a flutter fragment, which behave strange.

above Android API 29, flutter fragment will render above first fragment after the detail activity pop out of stack .

under Android API 29, flutter fragment always render above all views in the main activity.

I create this [repository](https://github.com/chdo002/float_fragment.git) to reproduce this error.

This [unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347650/flutter-embedded-fragment-renders-above-other-views-when-scrolling) is similar to mine.

this code  shows how I reuse fragments

```
    private void switchTo(String tag) {

        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (tag.equals("home")) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationsFragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(notificationsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

this is where flutter fragment add to the view

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        if (mRepGoalsFlutterFragment1 == null) {
            mRepGoalsFlutterFragment1 = FlutterFragment.withNewEngine()
                    .build();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.card_view7,
                            mRepGoalsFlutterFragment1,
                            TAG_REP_GOALS_FLUTTER_FRAGMENT_1)
                    .commit();
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your posts with Github issue(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59968),the solution is create self class extends FlutterFragment, get flutterSurfaceView in the **onFlutterSurfaceViewCreated**.

```
    private FlutterSurfaceView flutterView;
    @Override
    public void onFlutterSurfaceViewCreated(@NonNull FlutterSurfaceView flutterSurfaceView) {
        super.onFlutterSurfaceViewCreated(flutterSurfaceView);
        LogUtils.d(TAG, "onFlutterSurfaceViewCreated开始");
        this.flutterView = flutterSurfaceView;
        LogUtils.d(TAG, "onFlutterSurfaceViewCreated结束");
    }
```

Then setVisibility in onResume.

```
@SuppressLint("解决FlutterFragment切换到前台显示的问题")
void updateFlutterViewVisibility() {
    if (flutterView == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (isFlutterHidden) {
        flutterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        flutterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    LogUtils.d(TAG, "onResume开始");
    super.onResume();
    updateFlutterViewVisibility();
    LogUtils.d(TAG, "onResume结束");
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    LogUtils.d(TAG, "onHiddenChanged开始");
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    isFlutterHidden = hidden;
    updateFlutterViewVisibility();
    LogUtils.d(TAG, "onHiddenChanged结束");
}
```

Create your self class extends FlutterFragment like this:

```
FlutterFragment.CachedEngineFragmentBuilder(
        YourFlutterFragment::class.java,
        YourFlutterFragmentEngineId
    )
        .shouldAttachEngineToActivity(false)
        .build<YourFlutterFragment>()
```

Answer (score 2):

By default FlutterFragment use a SurfaceView to render its Flutter content. SurfaceView can’t be interleaved in the middle of an Android View hierarchy. A SurfaceView must either be the bottommost View in the hierarchy, or the topmost View in the hierarchy. Therefore use TextureView instead of SurfaceView to resolve your issue

```
FlutterFragment flutterFragment = FlutterFragment.withNewEngine()
.renderMode(FlutterView.RenderMode.texture)
.build();
```

Comment: Should this issue be handled by the developer or Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

In my Fragment, I have to detachFlutterEngine myself to fix this problem.

```
private FlutterView myFlutterView;
private boolean isFlutterHidden = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    myFlutterView = FlutterBoostUtils.findFlutterView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    isFlutterHidden = hidden;
    updateFlutterViewHidden();
}

@SuppressLint("VisibleForTests")
void updateFlutterViewHidden() {
    if (myFlutterView == null) return;
    if (isFlutterHidden) {
        myFlutterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        myFlutterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateFlutterViewHidden();
}
```